# Using long2ip for IPv6?

Tags: php, ip, ipv6

To generate a random IPv4 address that's between a certain range, I do this:

```
$ip = long2ip(rand("16777215", "3758096384"));
echo $ip;
```

However, `long2ip` doesn't appear to work with IPv6 addresses.

Is there anything similar to generate a random IPv6 address that's between a certain range?

Comment: This website appears to be able to convert decimals to IPv6 address, just not sure how they do it... http://www.webdnstools.com/dnstools/ipcalc

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.long2ip.php :
"Converts an long integer address into a string in (IPv4) Internet standard dotted format"

Read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35208011/4067232